# How can I do exponential regression in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regression, exponential

can someone tell me how to do exponential regression or point me to a good explaination? I want to implement it in a javascript tool.
I know that theoretically, I have to create a discrepancy function, take its first derivation, set it equal to zero and solve for the three parameters of the exponential function, but is there a simplified algorithm that allows me to do this without solving each time and so on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have little experience with exponential (nonlinear) regression, but it looks like there's a javascript tool here for demonstrating:

http://statpages.org/nonlin.html

If you view source, you'll see the javascript behind that demo.